# Some input on how to proceed on the migration from SQL Server

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, database-migration

I'm migrating from SQL Server to Azure SQL and I'd like to ask you who have more experience in Azure(I have basically none) some questions just to understand what I need to do to have the best migration.

Today I do a lot of cross database queries in some of my tasks that runs once a week. I execute SPs, run selects, inserts and updates cross the dbs. I solved the executions of SPs by using external data sources and sp_execute_remote. But as far as I can see it's only possible to select from an external database, meaning I won't be able to do any inserts or updates cross the dbs. Is that correct? If so, what's the best way to solve this problem?

I also read about cross db calls are slow. Does this mean it's slower that in SQL Server? I want to know if I'll face a slower process comparing to what I have today.

What I really need is some good guidelines on how to do the best migration without spending loads of time with trial and error. I appreciate any help in this matter.

Comment: `Today I do a lot of cross database queries in some of my tasks that runs once a week`,when you migrate to azure,are you keeping some databases on onpremises

Comment: No, everything will be on Azure

Comment: check this:https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/querying-remote-databases-in-azure-sql-db/

Comment: Thanks but I can't see any example for an insert on an external db.

Comment: You can definitely insert on an Azure SQL db... I connect via odbc from R after having set up a read/write connection. So you can still do those steps... but if you don't do R then I'm not sure. Anyway, your question is a bit strange... you're talking about doing the migration, but also about the reprecussions of the migration?

Answer (score 0):

Cross database transactions are not supported in Azure SQL DB.  You connect to a specific database, and can't use 3 part names or use the USE syntax.
You could open up two different connections from your program, one to each database.  It doesn't allow any kind of transactional consistency, but would allow you to retrieve data from one Azure SQL DB and insert it in another.

So, at least now, if you want your database in Azure and you can't avoid cross-database transactions, you'll be using an Azure VM to host SQL Server.